# Recursive iteration over parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015, c++14, variadic-templates

I'm currently trying to implement a function, which accepts some `data` and a parameter-pack `...args`. Inside I call another function, which recursively iterates the given arguments.

Sadly I'm having some issues to compile it. Apparently the compiler keeps trying to compile the recursive function, but not the overload to stop the recursion.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue is ?

```
class Sample
{
public:
    template<class ...TArgs, std::size_t TotalSize = sizeof...(TArgs)>
    static bool ParseCompositeFieldsXXX(const std::vector<std::string> &data, TArgs &&...args)
    {
        auto field = std::get<0>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...));

        //bool ok = ParseField(field, 0, data);
        auto x = data[0];
        bool ok = true;

        if (TotalSize > 1)
            return ok && ParseCompositeFields<1>(data, std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
        return ok;
    }

private:
    template<std::size_t Index, class ...TArgs, std::size_t TotalSize = sizeof...(TArgs)>
    static bool ParseCompositeFields(const std::vector<std::string> &data, TArgs &&...args)
    {
        auto field = std::get<Index>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...));

        //bool ok = ParseField(field, Index, data);
        auto x = data[Index];
        bool ok = true;

        if (Index < TotalSize)
            return ok && ParseCompositeFields<Index + 1>(data, std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
        return ok;
    }

    template<std::size_t Index>
    static bool ParseCompositeFields(const std::vector<std::string> &data)
    {
        volatile int a = 1 * 2 + 3;
    }
};

int wmain(int, wchar_t**)
{
    short       x1 = 0;
    std::string x2;
    long long   x3 = 0;

    Sample::ParseCompositeFieldsXXX({ "1", "Sxx", "-5,32" }, x1, x2, x3);

    return 0;
}
```

> \utility(446):    error C2338: tuple index out of bounds
>   ...
>   \main.cpp(56):    note: see reference to class template
>   instantiation 'std::tuple_element<3,std::tuple>' being compiled

Comment: Your parameter pack is not decreasing, but index is increasing. You need either `if constexpr` at the very top or a little bit changed recursion.

Comment: @Incomputable Tried it with `if constexpr`, but VS'15 supports only C++14. Do you know how the recursion can be changed to work ? I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Recursion is grandpa's approach at this. Think deeper. You don't need recursion.

Comment: Can you check my solution? I got really interested in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Alternative approach

You seem to be using rather old technique here. [Simple expansion](https://godbolt.org/g/DAhCbW) is what you're searching for:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Sample
{
    template <std::size_t index, typename T>
    static bool parse_field(T&& field, const std::vector<std::string>& data)
    {
        return true;
    }

    template <typename Tuple, std::size_t ... sequence>
    static bool parse_impl(Tuple&& tup, const std::vector<std::string>& data, std::index_sequence<sequence...>)
    {
        using expander = bool[];
        expander expansion{parse_field<sequence>(std::get<sequence>(tup), data)...};

        bool result = true;
        for (auto iter = std::begin(expansion); iter != std::end(expansion); ++iter)
        {
            result = result && *iter;
        }

        return result;
    }

public:
    template<class ...TArgs, std::size_t TotalSize = sizeof...(TArgs)>
    static bool ParseCompositeFieldsXXX(const std::vector<std::string> &data, TArgs &&...args)
    {

        return parse_impl(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...),
                          data, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(TArgs)>{});
    }


};

int main()
{
    short       x1 = 0;
    std::string x2;
    long long   x3 = 0;

    Sample::ParseCompositeFieldsXXX({ "1", "Sxx", "-5,32" }, x1, x2, x3);

    return 0;
}
```

If you're looking at something like array, then it is array. Don't use recursion unless required, as it usually makes it complicated. Of course there are exceptions though.

### Making it better

As you can see, one doesn't even need a class here. Just remove it.

### Possible problems

One problem might arise if the order of invocation matters. IIRC, before C++17 this doesn't have strong evaluation order, so it might fail you sometimes.

Comment: It looks good, but I see one problem. How am I going to get the index in `parse_field` in your code ?

Comment: You can create intermediate structs rather than bool array. After expansion is completed, use iterators to determine the index. Why do you need index anyway? Creating intermediate structs will also enforce evaluation order. Though, temporaries will not work anymore and will cause UB. They shouldn’t be allowed anyway.

Comment: `After expansion is completed` - The correctly ordered index is neccessary during execution / expansion for logic inside the `parse_field` as you named it.

Comment: create structs, don’t execute anything. Execute them during runtime pass, not expansion. Execution and expansion are not the same thing.

Comment: I see now. It is solvable, but more complex. I’ll post solution later. I’m sure it still gonna be much more prettier.

Comment: Ah well, the function is being executed when initializing the variable `expansion` in your code. This function requires the _correct_ index parameter. That's what I mean.

Comment: @Blacktempel, I got the solution working with index thing. As pretty as it was

Comment: Thank you. Haven't heard of `std::index_sequence` so far.

Comment: @Blacktempel, I believe you also would want to learn SFINAE. It is pretty powerful feature of the language. With that, your template metaprogramming skillset will be more complete.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have an idea what the issue is ?

The crucial point are the lines:

```
if (Index < TotalSize)
            return ok && ParseCompositeFields<Index + 1>(data, std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
```

First of all, to be *logically* correct, the condition should read `Index < TotalSize - 1`., as tuple element counts are zero-based.
Furthermore, even if `Index == TotalSize - 1`, the compiler is still forced to instantiate `ParseCompositeFields<Index + 1>` (as it has to compile the if-branch), which effectively is `ParseCompositeFields<TotalSize>`. This however will lead to the error your got when trying to instantiate `std::get<TotalSize>`.

So in order to conditionally compile the if-branch only when the condition is fulfilled, you *would* have to use `if constexpr(Index < TotalSize - 1)` (see on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/fCbtyY)). For C++14, you have to fall back on using template specializations and function objects:

```
class Sample
{
    template<std::size_t Index, bool>
    struct Helper {
         template<class ...TArgs, std::size_t TotalSize = sizeof...(TArgs)>
        static bool ParseCompositeFields(const std::vector<std::string> &data, TArgs &&...args)
        {
            auto field = std::get<Index>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...));

            //bool ok = ParseField(field, Index, data);
            auto x = data[Index];
            bool ok = true;

            return ok && Helper<Index + 1, (Index < TotalSize - 1)>::ParseCompositeFields(data, std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
        }
    };

    template<std::size_t Index>
    struct Helper<Index, false> {
        template<class ...TArgs, std::size_t TotalSize = sizeof...(TArgs)>
        static bool ParseCompositeFields(const std::vector<std::string> &data, TArgs &&...args) {
            volatile int a = 1 * 2 + 3;
            return true;
        }
    };

public:
    template<class ...TArgs, std::size_t TotalSize = sizeof...(TArgs)>
    static bool ParseCompositeFieldsXXX(const std::vector<std::string> &data, TArgs &&...args)
    {
        auto field = std::get<0>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...));

        //bool ok = ParseField(field, 0, data);
        auto x = data[0];
        bool ok = true;

       return ok && Helper<1, (TotalSize > 1)>::ParseCompositeFields(data, std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    }

};
```

Comment: This is clear to me. I also clearly tagged it as C++14, not C++17. That's the problem.

Comment: @Blacktempel If this is clear to you, why do you ask then?

Comment: @Jodocus, is our solutions give the same result? Mine is below. I think we don't need recursion here.